# Differential Equations Integrating y by x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

This may be a bit of a silly questions, but when solving a differential equation by finding an integrating factor, is it possible to integrate a function of y and x by x? I understand that in multi variable calculus the y would be treated as a constant, but I am not sure why the same does not apply in differential equations. For example...

For the differential equation $y' + y =xy^3$

The way to solve it would be to multiply the whole equation by $-2y^{-3} $ then solve for the integrating factor which would be $e^{-2x}$.

But I'm wondering why we even need to get rid of the y terms on the right side of the equations. Can we solve the equations as such...

$y' + y = xy^3$

$y'*e^x + e^xy =xy^3e^x$

$\int d(ye^x) = \int xy^3e^x dx$

I understand that this method is incorrect, but I am having trouble understanding why separation of variables are absolutely necessary in differential equations.

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$, or $y(x)$.

Comment: Are you interested in seeing alternative methods of solving this differential equation? $$\text{Method 1: Bernoulli and Integrating Factor.}$$ $$\text{Method 2: Substitute $y=\frac{1}{z}$ and then solve.}$$ $$\text{Method 3: Your method.}$$ Are you interested in other solutions?

Comment: @Axion004 I heard about method 2, but would be interested in reading more on method 1. If you have any good resources on mind, would be greatly appreciated if you send those over. If not, I'll just do a quick google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'e^x + e^xy =xy^3e^x$$
Then make it separable:
$$(ye^x)' =xy^3e^x$$
$$\dfrac {d(ye^x)}{y^3e^{3x}} =xe^{-2x}dx$$
And integrate:
$$\int \dfrac {d(ye^x)}{(ye^{x})^3} =\int xe^{-2x}dx$$
Otherwise you can't evaluate the integral: $$I=\int y^3xe^xdx$$
Because $y$ is not a constant but a function of the variable $x$.